# Making line full line of text in paragraph

Tags: html

When I write a long paragraph every other line is not a full line of text. How do I fix this? it just looks like crap when looking at the code.

[image]

Comment: you mean in the code or on the browser? if you mean in code, then what editor are you using VSC or what? it depends on your writing and the viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Visual Studio Code setting, you can access the vscode json file settings by pressing `F1` and typing `>Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`, select the first option and it will open the file.

Paste the line `"html.format.wrapLineLength": 0`, inside the json object.

For more info: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting

Comment: did that it did not work

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<pre></pre>` to make sure your text `\n` (enter) to be readable into your browser, you can see the example below.

```html
<div style="max-width: 100%">
<pre>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. 

It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur,

from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. 

This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. 

Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="max-width: 100%; line-height:30px ">
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. 

It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur,

from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. 

This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. 

Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use line height according to requirement and space you want between 2 lines.

Comment: I think question want to fix format in code ( or IDE ) and not in browser